# iOS - detect which cell is being dragged

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` and some cells in there. I was wondering, is there a way to know which cell was tapped on when the dragging began?

I know there is `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but that does not fire when the dragging starts.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`? There are all kinds of methods related to moving rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` of `UITableViewDataSource` protocol tells you the cell that was dragged and the position that it is about to be dropped.

It is only triggered when the drop happens.